Fundamental proof of integral inequality
I would like to introduce the following inequality
$$ \theta_{ii} \theta_{jj} \geq \theta_{ij}^2 \quad (\text{no summation over } i,j)\, , $$
where $\theta_{ii} = \int_m (x_j^2 + x_k^2) \, \mathrm{d}m \; (i,j,k \; \text{different})$ and $\theta_{ij} = - \int_m x_i x_j \, \mathrm{d}m \; (i \neq j)$ are the moment and product of interia respectively, in a mechanics course for undergraduate engineering students.
The beginning of a straighforward proof might look something like the following.
Without loss of generality, let us set $i=1, j=2, k=3$. We then have
$$
\begin{align}
\theta_{11} \theta_{22} - \theta_{12}^2 
&= 
\int_m (x_2^2 + x_3^2) \, \mathrm{d}m \cdot \int_m (x_1^2 + x_3^2) \, \mathrm{d}m - \left( \int_m x_1 x_2 \, \mathrm{d}m \right)^2 \\
&\geq 
\int_m x_2^2 \, \mathrm{d}m \cdot \int_m x_1^2 \, \mathrm{d}m - \left( \int_m x_1 x_2 \, \mathrm{d}m \right)^2 \\
&= \lvert\lvert x_2 \rvert\rvert_{L^2}^2 \cdot \lvert\lvert x_1 \rvert\rvert_{L^2}^2 - \langle x_1,x_2 \rangle_{L^2}^2 \\
& \overset{\text{C.S.}}{\geq} \lvert \langle x_1,x_2 \rangle_{L^2} \rvert^2 - \langle x_1,x_2 \rangle_{L^2}^2 \geq 0
\end{align}
$$
where in the last row, the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality $\lvert\lvert f \rvert\rvert_{L^2} \lvert\lvert g \rvert\rvert_{L^2} \geq \lvert \langle f, g \rangle_{L^2} \rvert$ was used .
My problem with this proof is that, to make this clear to my students, I would have to give an introduction into functional analysis, which I would like to avoid. As the integrands here are rather simple, I'm hoping there is a more fundamental proof, which students with a background in multivariable calculus can understand.
So, my question is: Is there an even more fundamental proof of this inequality, that can be understood with a basic knowledge of multivariable calculus?

Is this Einstein notation?

Fair point. It's not. I changed the problem description slightly to hopefully make it clearer.

You could try reproducing the proof of Cauchy-Schwarz just on your set of functions using a simple quadratic. It only requires linearity and positive of some integrals and single variable calculus.

@whpowell96 Maybe I'm missing something but wouldn't I still need to introduce the L2 norm and scalar product and explain why Cauchy-Schwarz can be used for infinite dimensional vector spaces?

Here is a proof that proves Cauchy-Schwarz only on your set of functions using elementary methods without explicitly involving any function spaces. Define $u(x) = tx_i+x_j$, then
$$
I =\int_m u(x)^2~\mathrm{d}m = \int_m (tx_i+x_j)^2~\mathrm{d}m = t^2\alpha_{ii} + 2t\alpha_{ij}+\alpha_{jj}\geq0~\forall t,
$$
where $\alpha_{ij} = \int_m x_ix_j~\mathrm{d}m$. We know that the expression is nonnegative since it is the integral of a nonnegative function for every $t$. However, notice that this expression is a quadratic polynomial in $t$ with coefficients $A = \alpha_{ii}$, $B = 2\alpha_{ij}$, and $C=\alpha_{jj}$. For this polynomial to be nonnegative for all $t$, it can have at most one real root. Therefore, we must have that $B^2-4AC \leq 0$. Substituting, we obtain
$$4\alpha_{ij}^2 - 4\alpha_{ii}\alpha_{jj} \leq 0\implies \alpha_{ij}^2 \leq \alpha_{ii}\alpha_{jj},$$
as desired. One needs to show that $A\geq 0$ for this to work, but that is simple.
